# send_keys of selenium in pyhon does not work

Tags: python, selenium, sendkeys

I am using python3, and want to send messages in Instagram using python, package selenium.
the code works great before. Today most of the time the send_keys() does not work.
I increase the sleep() time to be sure that it is not the internet speed problem. still, it does not work. Any idea? or any alternative ways to send text in a box (I am using python)?

this is the code:

```
           webdriver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'+ hashtag_list[tag] + '/')
            sleep(5)
            check='//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div/div[%d]/div[%d]/a/div' %(i,x)
            sleep(10)   
    #'//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[%s]/a/div' % (x)
            first_thumbnail = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(check)
            first_thumbnail.click()
            sleep(10)
            webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[2]/button/span').click()
            sleep(10)
            comment_box = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/textarea')
            sleep(20)
            comment_box.send_keys("Hi")  # this line does not work
            sleep(10)
            webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/button').click()
            sleep(10)
        except:
            print("Oops!")
            sleep(10)
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure comment_box is actually a valid webelement by printing it? Just to make sure the selector is correct?
Because it should normally work, but perhaps Instagram is somehow doing something to block it.

Comment: yes, it is a valid webelement. right now it works 10% of times. May be the Instagram blocked it! any other suggestion to use instead of send_keys?  maybe other methods can work

Comment: Maybe try ```element.send_keys("text here", Keys.ARROW_DOWN)``` as they demonstrate on the selenium page (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html).
Maybe the simulation makes the difference for Instagram, because when I just tried, it worked both with and without that addition (not on Instagram, but on a textarea)
Also, try if it works on different elements so you can narrow down the potential cause.

Comment: Does it work anywhere else (in general or on Instagram)? Like regular text inputs (e.g. login form type of input's)

Comment: yes it works in general. also on instagram, for login (username and password) it works. just when I logged in, it does not work for sending comments

Comment: You can use setattribute for value of that textarea.